# Kotlin equivalent of C# BitConverter.ToString

Tags: c#, android, kotlin, mobile, c#-4.0

It's BitConverter.ToString(blabla) same with blabla.toString?

Example:

```
int values = 1500;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(values);

byte[] bits = new byte[2];
bits.SetValue(bytes[0], 0);
bits.SetValue(bytes[1], 1);

string hex = BitConverter.ToString(bits);
string hexHub1 = hex.Substring(0, hex.IndexOf("-"));
string hexHub2 = hex.Substring(hex.IndexOf("-") +1,2);
```

And get "DC-05"

How can i implement anything like this in kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`byteArray.toString()` is used to convert `ByteArray` to `String`. On the other hand, `contentToString()` will result elements in the array.

```
val byteArray = "Hello".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
println(byteArray.contentToString()) // this will print numbers 
println(byteArray.toString(Charsets.UTF_8))
```